# How to send email to a specific organic groups role using rules?

Tags: rules, organic-groups

I'm trying to set up a Rule to send an email to organic group members with a specific og role, in this case 'captain', when new group content 'Ticket' is created.

I've been able to set it up for all members of a group, even for group managers, but I can't figure out how to filter it just for a specific og role.

```
{ "rules_alert_captains" : {
"LABEL" : "Alert Captains",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "og", "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert--ticket" : { "bundle" : "ticket" } },
"IF" : [ { "og_entity_is_group_content" : { "entity" : [ "node" ] } } ],
"DO" : [
  { "og_get_members" : {
      "USING" : { "group_content" : [ "node" ] },
      "PROVIDE" : { "group_members" : { "group_members" : "List of group members" } }
    }
  },
  { "LOOP" : {
      "USING" : { "list" : [ "group-members" ] },
      "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
      "DO" : [
        { "mail" : {
            "to" : [ "group-members:0:mail" ],
            "subject" : "Hello",
            "message" : "This is an email",
            "language" : [ "" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

Edit: My PHP attempt

```
{ "rules_alert_captains_php" : {
"LABEL" : "Alert Captains PHP",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "og", "php", "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert--ticket" : { "bundle" : "ticket" } },
"IF" : [ { "og_entity_is_group_content" : { "entity" : [ "node" ] } } ],
"DO" : [
  { "og_get_members" : {
      "USING" : { "group_content" : [ "node" ] },
      "PROVIDE" : { "group_members" : { "group_members" : "List of group members" } }
    }
  },
  { "LOOP" : {
      "USING" : { "list" : [ "group-members" ] },
      "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
      "DO" : [
        { "php_eval" : { "code" : "$og_roles = og_get_user_roles($node-\u003Egroup_audience[\u0027und\u0027][0][\u0027gid\u0027], $list_item-\u003Euid, true);\r\n\r\nif($og_roles) {\r\n  $og_role_names = og_get_user_roles_name($og_roles);\r\n}\r\n\r\nif(in_array(\u0027captain\u0027, $og_role_names)) {\r\n\/\/ or send an email\r\ndrupal_set_message(\u0022message going to be sent to user $list_item-\u003Ename\u0022);\r\n}" } }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

Comment: good that you included already the exported rule. What is your specific question related to that rule? FYI I do not see anything in it related to that "specific og role" in it, so what is it that this rule is doing (or not) so far?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Hi, unfortunately this is where I got stuck. I cannot find a way to filter for custom made og roles. 

I also tried a php solution (I edited it into the original question above) to try and filter for the og role "captain" but got back the following error "Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in C:\Users\SeanB\Sites\devdesktop\stupiddrupaltricks\includes\common.inc on line 8051"